# Text moving to next line in Bootstrap Panel

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have attached screenshot of bootstrap panel(repeated). the second text paragraph (Taj) displays in next line and hence the chevron style (padding-top:50%) doesn't align to exact middle(or center) of the panel.How do I resolve this issue?

Also, I need to chnage the color of the body text and chevron to blue on mouseover.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

```css
.chevronAtRight{
 font-size:20px;
 padding-top:80%;
}
.hoverChevronFont{
 color:#49B4E8;
 font-family: 'Avenir', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';
 font-style: 'Book';
}
```

```html
<p class="panelTextFont14 panelText" ng-attr-title="{{reservation.resortName}}">
          {{reservation.resortName}}
         </p>

...

<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
         <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right chevronAtRight"></i>
         </p>
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of the chevron :

```
.glyphicon:hover {
   color:#49B4E8; 
}
```

But for change the color of all body text you need to use jquery onmouseover.

And for center the chevron try something like this :

```
.vcenter {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: none;
}
```

And in your html :

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 vcenter">
```

Comment: thanks, I can't use jquery, but i can use AngularJs. So how can i achive eit in AJS?

Comment: Use the event ngMouseover and ngMouseleave to change the style of body text. Check the doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave

Comment: thanks, but i already have one expression for it. how can i add multiple? - ng-mouseover="searchReservationVm.getTitle(reservation.firstName,reservation.title,reservation.suffix)"

Comment: Its not still aligning at center. Let me check!